# Json.getproperty giving undefined

Tags: javascript, json, sapui5

I have the following code where I need do draw a table using sap ui5 JSON Model. When I run the program I'm getting no data in the output table. I json.getProperty alert I'm getting alert output as undefined.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <!-- Load UI5, select gold reflection theme and the "commons" and "table"  control libraries -->
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
     type="text/javascript"
      src="https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
     data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
     data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.commons,sap.ui.table"></script>

<script>
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/XMII/Illuminator?QueryTemplate=ZTest/QueryTemplates/table%20list&content-type=text/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { // callback called when data is received
        var jsonModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        jsonModel.loadData(data);
        sap.ui.getCore().setModel(jsonModel);

        var weatherTable = new sap.ui.table.Table({
            title : "Current Weather Details",
            visibleRowCount : 20
        });

        weatherTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
            label : new sap.ui.commons.Label({text : "Tablename"}),               
            template : new sap.ui.commons.TextView().bindText("TableName")                
        }));

        var oModel1 = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();  

        var aData = jsonModel.getProperty("/Rowsets/Rowset/Row");            
        oModel1.setData({modelData : aData});            
        weatherTable.setModel(oModel1);  
        weatherTable.bindAggregation("rows","/modelData");  
        weatherTable.placeAt('content'); 


        var dataLayout = new sap.ui.layout.HorizontalLayout({
            id : "dataLayout", // sap.ui.core.ID                
        });

        var Tablename = new sap.ui.commons.TextView({
            id : "Tablename",
            text : '{TableName}'
        })

        dataLayout.addContent(Tablename);
        dataLayout.placeAt("content");
    }
});
</script>

</head>
<body class='sapUiBody'>
    <div id='content'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi! I put it an edit to clean up the code a bit so that others can try to spot the problem more easily. However, at the moment, others can't run the code themselves because they don't have the file for the AJAX request. I'd recommend changing this so others can run the code on their machines.

Comment: Yes, please do a request to ```/XMII/Illuminator?QueryTemplate=ZTest/QueryTemplates/table%20list&content-type=text/json``` manually and post the resulting JSON here

Comment: If I'm using a file from local folder it's working fine but when I'm trying to use link I'm getting error.